# Prevent Excel "Convert text to columns wizard" from converting text to date

Tags: excel

I have an excel file with 3000 rows. The value in A1 is 7/2-79 and in A2 7/2-80 and so on. When I tried to split these values using convert text to columns wizard, I get 7 in B1 and Feb-79 in C1 where I want 7 and 2-79 respectively.

I formatted the destination cells as text, but it not worked. Then I formatted the whole sheet as text, but no change in result.

Please help me.

Edit: While using Convert text to columns wizard, I tried changing column data format from "general" to "text" too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried it and you have to actually select the column with the 2-79 (step 3 of the wizard) and then fill the radio button that says text. If you only do it to the first column then you wont affect the one that's converting to a date.

Comment: Can you elaborate, please?

Comment: I just followed the steps you outlined in your original post, but when you get to step 3 of the wizard, where you would select the format of the data in the columns, you have to do it on a column by column basis. I chose text format after selecting the column with 2-79 in it, and it displayed exactly the way you indicated you wanted it displayed

Comment: Oh, that worked! I didn't know that I could click inside the data preview! That image was really helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Feb-79 is correct. Feb-79 = 2/79.

if you would like a string of text you can make

```
C1=Feb-79
D1=MONTH(C1)&"/"&RIGHT(YEAR(C1),2)
D1=2/29
```

or if you want to preserve the date value; right click on the range (cells or column) and Format Cells> Number tab > Custom category > Type: "m/yy" without ""

or you can do this

```
C1=Feb-79
D1=TEXT(C1,"m/yy")
D1=2/29
```

To get the same effect

Hope this helps.